# How to update aws cloud formation stack with Aws codepipeline

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-codepipeline, aws-cloudformation-custom-resource

I am new to serverless apps CICD with aws Codepipeline. I am trying to update the stack using aws codepipeline, but it's not working properly. When I was checking the endpoint url in postman it's getting the old response only, Not getting the latest changes response. I have selected create or update stack deploy with cloud formation in Codepipeline.

Can anyone help on this. 
Thankin advance

Comment: Would you mind sharing how you set up the codepipeline and how your cloudformation stack looks like?

Comment: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/continuous-delivery-codepipeline-basic-walkthrough.html   Please follow the document